# Don't we need a conjunction between two clauses?

Tags: conjunctions, commas, clauses, lists

Isn't a conjunction such as ***as*** needed bewteen the two bolded clauses? Or, if it is just okay, I want to know why.

> The desire for fame has its roots in the experience of neglect, in
>   injury. No one would want to be famous who hadn’t also, somewhere in
>   the past, been made to feel extremely insignificant. We sense the need
>   for a great deal of admiring attention when we have been painfully
>   exposed to earlier deprivation. Perhaps one’s parents were hard to
>   impress. **They never noticed one much, they were so busy on other
>   things**, focusing on other famous people, unable to have or express
>   kind feelings, or just working too hard. There were no bedtime stories
>   and one’s school reports weren’t the subject of praise and admiration.
>   That’s why one dreams that one day the world will pay attention. When
>   we’re famous, our parents will have to admire us too (which throws up
>   an insight into one of the great signs of good parenting: that your
>   child has no desire to be famous).

https://www.theschooloflife.com/thebookoflife/your-desire-to-be-famous-and-the-problems-it-will-bring-you/

Answer (score 2):

This is a comma splice.  It is often considered a flaw in written English (though a fairly common one, so it can't be called a grammatical mistake.

The usual way this could be punctuated is to use a semicolon to indicate two sentences with closely related meaning.

> They never noticed one much; they were so busy on other things, focusing on other famous people, unable to have or express kind feelings, or just working too hard.